# iPhone - best approach to a URL table?

Tags: iphone, ios, url, nsstring

I want to be able to have a table of 15 - 20 different URL's that I want to use as part of an embedded browser on my iPhone application.

I want these to be in an external file that I can easily change when the URL'S change.

So I want to be able to access the URL's via a variable in my code and then be easily able to change the URL value of that variable in the one external file.

In Android the approach taken was to have a url_strings.xml file and use that from resources.

But what would be the best approach on iPhone to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to use a [plist](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFPropertyLists/CFPropertyLists.html).

Comment: Word for word what I was going to say.